# How to deploy to Now 2 without `build` and `public`?

Tags: vercel

I've been using Now and I want to upgrade to Now 2 https://zeit.co/ but the problem is for Now 2 I need to have a build script in which I just wrote:

```
echo 'built'
```

But then it says it cannot find the "public" folder - I don't need to actually build my project so there would be no public folder.

I tried changing my build script to

```
cp -r . ./public
```

This is not working either, it says `cp: cannot copy a directory, ‘.’, into itself, ‘./public’`.

So is there a setting where I can get Now 2 to work just like Now?

Comment: This is difficult to answer because it is not clear how the project is structured. If it is a static site, you don't need a build script. But it sounds like its not static and you have a package.json so you could try `mkdir public && echo "Hello" > public/index.html"`. Then you'll have a home page and your functions can live in `/api` directory.

Comment: Does Now 2 only support serving static pages? Can I run an app.js for example and serve dynamically?

Comment: Yes, you can use serverless functions in the /api directory. https://zeit.co/docs/v2/serverless-functions/introduction

Comment: @styfle this serverless function looks like a breaking change to me. It seems to force me to use express like framework instead of creating my own server through `net`. So I guess in V2 we lost the fine grained control over how we will process the request...Also how does this serverless api support websocket?

Comment: It is a breaking change which is why there was a major version bump 1.0 => 2.0 https://zeit.co/docs/v2/platform/limits#websockets

Comment: @styfle I will stick with V1 then

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Project Settings](https://zeit.co/blog/advanced-project-settings), which has just been released.

Comment: Can u write an answer rather than giving a link? I read the link and was not able to figure out very quickly.